# Reference Spinner by Tag

Tags: java, android

I have a ScrollView with few dynamically created Spinners. Each spinner is marked by Tag in cycle and has common setOnItemSelectedListener. But when the event occur, I have this error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference" on string marked by ***. Looks like it is not working with spinner. Same time, it is working good with ImageView. Why?

```
void ShowList() {
        LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nrlinLayout);
        LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        linLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < Trans.size(); i++) {
            View item = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rnd, linLayout, false);
            ImageView ivDelete=(ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.rndDeleted);
            ivDelete.setTag(i);
            ivDelete.setOnClickListener(v-> {
                Trans.remove(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
                ShowList();
            });
            Spinner sp=(Spinner) item.findViewById(R.id.rndspinner);
            acts = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Actions);
            acts.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(acts);
            sp.setTag(i);
            sp.setSelection(Trans.get(i)-1);
            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
***                   int ind = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                   Trans.set(ind, position + 1);
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                }
            });
            item.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            linLayout.addView(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **v** is the TextView for showing text in the spinner, so change `v.getTag()` to `parentView.getTag()`.

Comment: Where was my eyes! Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

i_A_mok answered in comments: v is the TextView for showing text in the spinner, so change v.getTag() to parentView.getTag().